# Update a record Field from an unbound text box on a form in ms access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form called [ADD_Individual_Info] that pops up when a user scans in with their ID Card and the barcode isn't in the database. However I have learned that some have just gotten new cards and the new barcode number isn't stored in the database. I have a text box [txt_copyEmail] on the form [ADD_Individual_Info] that allows the user to search their email address to find their record in the database. This is so they don't have to retype their info in again. On the same form I another text box [txt_EDIPI] with the newly scanned barcode number. I want to just update the record on my table with the new number from text box [txt_EDIPI]. The Form [ADD_Individual_Info] has a sub form [SubIndividualInfo] on it and its Source [sfrm_User_Item_Info] and its record source is [qry_User_Item_Info] this only displays the users email address and their name. I have on after update event on text box [txt_copyEmail]. That looks like this:

```
Private Sub txt_copyemail_AfterUpdate()
Call search_email
Me.txt_UserEmail.Value = Me.SubIndividualInfo.Form.[UserEmail]
Me.txt_UserName.Value = Me.SubIndividualInfo.Form.[UserName]
Me.txt_Office.Value = Me.SubIndividualInfo.Form.[Office]
Me.txt_Rank_Title.Value = Me.SubIndividualInfo.Form.[Rank_Title]
Me.txt_PhoneNumber.Value = Me.SubIndividualInfo.Form.[PhoneNumber]
Me.txt_IndividualID.Value = Me.SubIndividualInfo.Form.[EDIPI]
End Sub
```

my function code:

```
Function search_email()
Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "SELECT tbl_User_Info.UserName, tbl_User_Info.[UserEmail]," _
        & "tbl_User_Info.[Office]," _
        & "tbl_User_Info.[Rank_Title]," _
        & "tbl_User_Info.[EDIPI]," _
        & "tbl_User_Info.PhoneNumber FROM tbl_User_Info " _
        & "Where [UserEmail] LIKE '*" & Me.txt_copyemail & "*' "
    Me.SubIndividualInfo.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.SubIndividualInfo.Form.Requery
End Function
```

This is so the user can verify the info is still accurate and if so they just click a button [btn_SaveandClose]. its code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Btn_SaveandClose_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tbl_User_Info")
    rec.Edit
        rec("UserEmail") = Me.UserEmail
        rec("EDIPI") = Me.txt_EDIPI
        rec("UserName") = Me.UserName
        rec("Office") = Me.Office
        rec("Rank_Title") = Me.Rank_Title
        rec("PhoneNumber") = Me.PhoneNumber
        rec.Update
    rec.Close
    Set rec = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
Me.txt_UserEmail.Value = ""
Me.txt_UserName.Value = ""
Me.txt_Office.Value = ""
Me.txt_Rank_Title.Value = ""
Me.txt_PhoneNumber.Value = ""
Me.txt_IndividualID.Value = ""
Me.txt_EDIPI.Value = ""
Me.txt_copyemail.Value = ""
Call search_email
End Sub
```

It is not editing the record that is displayed on the form it just update the first record on the table it comes too with the new number in text box [txt_EDIPI]. any help with my code. Or if there is a better way to make this work I am open to a better way. thanks.

Comment: SQL to set form RecordSource could be simplified to: `SELECT * FROM tbl_User_Info Where [UserEmail] LIKE '*" & Me.txt_copyemail & "*'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code i used on my Save and Close Button. this was to add new or just update field. I give credit to User June7 for giving me the helpful hints.

```
If Me.chkAddNewInfo = True Then
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rec As Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tbl_User_Info")
    rec.AddNew
        rec("UserEmail") = Me.txt_UserEmail
        rec("EDIPI") = Me.txt_EDIPI
        rec("UserName") = Me.txt_UserName
        rec("Office") = Me.txt_Office
        rec("Rank_Title") = Me.txt_Rank_Title
        rec("PhoneNumber") = Me.txt_PhoneNumber
        rec.Update
    rec.Close
    Set rec = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
Else
    Me!SubIndividualInfo.Form.EDIPI.Value = Me.txt_EDIPI
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Open recordset with filter criteria that will return only 1 record:
`Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tbl_User_Info WHERE somefield=" & input)`

Or don't open recordset and just run an UPDATE action SQL with criteria for the desired record, example showing text, date, number type fields:

`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tablename SET field1 = '" & Me.tbxName1 & "', field2 = #" & Me.tbxName2 & "#, field3 = " & Me.tbxName3 & " WHERE ID=" & input`

Or don't do either and just edit record via form. If fields are included in form's RecordSource, simply:

`Me!fieldname = "some input"`

Comment: As my knowledge is limited on vba. What are you meaning by "run an UPDATE action SQL with Criteria for the desired record". do you have an example to help me out?

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: can you confirm that this is what you are referring to:```CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_User_Info " & _
    " SET EDIPI = '" & Me.txt_EDIPI & "'" & _
    ", UserEmail = '" & Me.txt_UserEmail & "'" & _
    ", UserName = '" & Me.txt_UserName & "'" & _
    ", Office = '" & Me.txt_Office & "'" & _
    ", Rank_Title = '" & Me.txt_Rank_Title & "'" & _
    ", PhoneNumber = '" & Me.txt_PhoneNumber & "'" & _
    " WHERE UserEmail=" & Me.txt_UserEmail.Value```

Comment: im getting a Sytanx error when running it. {(missing operator) in query expression 'USEREMAIL=new.mil@mail.mil'.} any ideas?

Comment: Since UserEmail is text type field, need apostrophe delimiters: `" WHERE UserEmail='" & Me.txt_UserEmail.Value & "'"`.

Comment: However, if you want to update only one field, there is no need to include all the other fields with any of these methods.

Comment: so this is what i did to make it work for me, i used the third option out of the three.  See my code in next comment..